# Twitter slang look up in R

Tags: r, twitter, analytics

I am writing a R script to analyse the sentiment of the tweets. I am using twitteR and ROAuth package to get the tweets based on some search key words.I am using the below code to achieve this.

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(httr)

# Set API Keys
api_key <- "xxxxxx"
api_secret <- "yyyyyy"
acs_token <- "aaxxbbbb"
access_token_secret <- "xyyzziiassss"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, acs_token, access_token_secret)
# Grab latest tweets
tweets_results <- searchTwitter('xfinity x1 netflix', n=1500)

# Loop over tweets and extract text    
feed_results = lapply(tweets_results, function(t) t$getText())
```

Now i am using the following function to clean up the tweets.

```
clean_text = function(x)
{
x = gsub("rt", "", x) # remove Retweet
x = gsub("@\\w+", "", x) # remove at(@)
x = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x) # remove punctuation
x = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x) # remove numbers/Digits
x = gsub("http\\w+", "", x)  # remove links http
x = gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", x) # remove tabs
x = gsub("^ ", "", x)  # remove blank spaces at the beginning
x = gsub(" $", "", x) # remove blank spaces at the end
try.error = function(z) #To convert the text in lowercase
{
y = NA
try_error = tryCatch(tolower(z), error=function(e) e)
if (!inherits(try_error, "error"))
y = tolower(z)
return(y)
}
x = sapply(x, try.error)
return(x)
```

Now after this clean up is done there are certain twitter slang words (like "Luv","BFF","BAE" etc.). For doing effective sentiment analytics these slang words needs to be transformed into standard English words. I was hoping to find a dictionary in R that would help me achieve this, but didn't find one. Does any one know about any such dictionary, if no can some one suggest me the best way to get around this problem.

Comment: http://www.netlingo.com/acronyms.php

Comment: Your code is loading the ‹plyr› package but you aren’t actually using it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for catching that. I was using it previously, but forgot to remove it.

Comment: @Venu Please accept the answer if it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some useful resources -

1. [Acronyms](http://www.netlingo.com/acronyms.php)
2. [Jargons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/download.html)
3. [More Slang](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/textmessageabbreviations.asp)

You can download the data and use it as a dictionary or lookup. Don't forget to remove stop words and perform stemming.